# Communicating acceptable string values in Swagger docs

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger

Spring Boot (Java) here. Does Swagger have any customizable/configurable fields that allows you to specify specific `String` values that an endpoint either accepts or returns?

For instance I might have an endpoint like so:

```
POST /v1/{accountId}/preferences
{
    "notificationTypes" : [

    ]
}
```

...that accepts an array of `notificationTypes` in its request entity. Perhaps my server only allows `AdminNotification` and `SimpleAlert` as the possible values for this `notificationTypes`, meaning:

```
POST /v1/{accountId}/preferences
{
    "notificationTypes" : [
        "SimpleAlert"
    ]
}
```

is valid but:

```
POST /v1/{accountId}/preferences
{
    "notificationTypes" : [
        "Hello"
    ]
}
```

throws a 400 Bad Request. I'd like to be able to communicate this in my Swagger docs. **Is this configuration possible via annotations?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a good solution would be to create an ENUM with the accepted values. This way, it will be automatically described in Swagger:

```
@ApiModelProperty(value= "Accepted values are :")
public NotificationTypes notificationTypes;


public enum NotificationTypes {SimpleAlerts, AdminNotifications}
```

In the generated specifications, it gives the following:

[image]

Have fun !

Comment: Good idea, I can't create enums without greatly refactoring my code base, **however** I *will* use the `@ApiModelProperty` annotation to get what I need... thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like -

> notificationTypes:
>        type: string
>         example: ["SimpleAlert", "otherValue"]

look - https://gyazo.com/1c8774fbf08410c19df0506a52a767d6
ref - https://swagger.io/docs/specification/adding-examples/